# Python Boto3 Lambda Upload Temp File

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm working on a Lambda that compresses image files in an S3 bucket. I'm able to download the image in the Lambda, compress it as a new file. I'm trying to upload the new file to the same S3 bucket and I keep on getting hit with the following error:

```
module initialization error: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Here's the code to upload:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.upload_file(filename,my_bucket,basename)
```

Here are the logs from one of the test uploads:

```
Getting ready to download Giggidy.png
This is what we're calling our temp file: /tmp/tmp6i7fvb6z.png
Let's compress /tmp/tmp6i7fvb6z.png
Compressed /tmp/tmp6i7fvb6z.png to /tmp/tmpmq23jj5c.png
Getting ready to upload /tmp/tmpmq23jj5c.png
File to Upload, filename: /tmp/tmpmq23jj5c.png
Mime Type: image/png
Name in Bucket, basename: tmpmq23jj5c.png
START RequestId: e9062ca9-ed2c-11e9-99ee-e3a40680ga9d Version: $LATEST
module initialization error: expected string or bytes-like object
END RequestId: e9062ca9-ed2c-11e9-99ee-e3a40680ga9d
```

How can I upload a file within the context of a Lambda?

UPDATE: I've uploaded my code to a gist for review: https://gist.github.com/kjenney/068531ffe01e14bb7a2351dc55592551

I also moved the boto3 client connection up in my script thinking that might be hosing the upload but I still get the same error in the same order. 'process' is my handler function.

Comment: Could you please show more of your code, especially your Lambda handler? How much of those logs are coming from Lambda? Where does everything before `START` come from? I suspect that the function isn't getting started correctly, so it's not even getting near your `upload_file()` command.

Comment: I ended up with a working solution by using aws-lambda-image. It's written in Node which is not my preferred language but it does work. I'd still love to get something working in Python3. That being said it does seem to be a lot more involved.

Comment: It really sounds like the Lambda function has not been configured to match your Handler name. If you want to get the Python version going, please add more details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein If you look at the code you can see that the entrypoint is process. I've got print statements sprinkled thru the code so it's definitely configured correctly. What I'm missing is how/why the upload_file portion is somehow not getting processed correctly even though there's definitely an image there that's getting read as bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this line:

```
client.upload_file(filename,my_bucket,basename)
```

From the documentation, the format is:

```
client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```

Note that the bucket name is a **string**. That's why the error says *expected string*.

However, your code sets `my_bucket` as:

```
my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket)
```

You should use the *name* of the bucket rather than the bucket *object*.